# Need help with this Probability Distribution Question

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Show that if X is a Poisson random variable with mean 1, then we have
$E(X^n) = E((X + 1)^{n−1})$.
Use this result to compute $Var(3X + 1)$ and $E(X^4)$.

Can the value of E(X) be computed by considering the value of n be 1 and then raised the power four be E($X^4$) and Variance would be 9*E($X$)?
Is there something wrong with this approach?

Comment: Are you asking if $\mathbb{E}(X)^4=\mathbb{E}(X^4)$? If this is your question, then the answer is no.

Comment: How would I go about computing the value?

Comment: Moreover, are you sure about the identiy your are giving ? $\mathbb{E}(X^n) = \mathbb{E}((X+1)^n-1)$ does not look right. Would the identity be $\mathbb{E}(X^n)=\mathbb{E}((X+1)^{n-1})$?

Comment: Yes you're right! I miss typed.

Comment: Then, $\mathbb{V}ar(X+c)=\mathbb{V}ar(X)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-\mathbb{E}(X)^2$, and for $\mathbb{E}(X^4)$ you can apply the identity twice to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. $Var(3X+1)=Var(3X)=9\cdot Var(X)$

But you can calculate $Var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$ with the given formula.

$E(X^n)=E((X + 1)^{n-1})$

Note that the the exponent is $n-1$.

$E(X^2)=E((X+1)^1)=E(X+1)$ and $[E(X)]^2=1$

*Second part*

$E(X^4)=E((X + 1)^{3})=E(X^3+3X^2+3X+1)=E(X^3)+3E(X^2)+3E(X)+1$

$E(X^3)$ can be calculated by using the given formula as well.